# Cosa significa "storicizzabile"?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> Voglio esaurire il tema di mia sorella, si tratta in tutto di due o tre episodi **storicizzabili**.

In seguito, l'autore spiega un paio di vicende accadute con sua sorella, quelle che lui ricorda della sua infanzia e giovinezza. Alla fine del brano, Gassman scrive:

> Il terzo episodio non lo ricordo, forse di altrettanto coloriti non ce ne furono più.

La mia domanda è sul significato del termine "storicizzabile" nella frase precedente: non l'ho trovato in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire?

Answer (score 1):

La parola **storicizzabili** (che possono essere storicizzati) deriva dal termine storicizzare:

**storiciżżare** v. tr. [der. di storico]. –

> Considerare, concepire come processo o divenire storico (s. la realtà,
>   lo spirito), o come momento di un più vasto processo storico; più in
>   generale, valutare in rapporto alla situazione storica, interpretare
>   in una prospettiva storica: s. una corrente letteraria, una scuola
>   filosofica. Fonte Enciclopedia Treccani.

Comment: Non capisco: cosa hanno a che vedere gli episodi con la sorella con la storia?

Comment: Potresti espandere la frase cosi: Voglio esaurire il tema di mia sorella, si tratta in tutto di due o tre episodi inseribili in un contesto storico

Comment: Ricordando il contesto in cui appare la frase che ho citato, non sono del tutto sicura che il significato sia questo. Gassman finisce il brano dicendo che forse c'era una terza vicenda con sua sorella, ma non la ricorda bene, quindi non la può spiegare. Adesso non ho il libro con me, quando arriverò a casa questa sera riporterò le parole esatte dell'autore. "Episodi storicizzabili" in questo contesto potrebbe significare "episodi che si possono raccontare come una storia"?

Comment: Se non vi è alcuna menzione di natura storica contemporanea al racconto, allora probabilmente è attribuibile il termine finale della definizione nella mia risposta "interpretare in una prospettiva storica", quasi come "cronoraccontare" qualcosa. Il contesto attribuisce un significato di natura più narrativa che storica.

Comment: Non c'è nessun riferimento a fatti della storia contemporanea: Gassman racconta quello che ricorda della sua infanzia e giovinezza.

Comment: Penso qui si voglia intendere che di tutta la vicenda della sorella, solo due episodi sono "degni" di uscire dalla cronaca e dalla memoria familiare e diventare "storia", cioè importanti.

Answer (score 1):

Significa "degni di nota" o in altri termini "che meritano di essere ricordati"

> Voglio esaurire il tema di mia sorella, si tratta in tutto di due o tre episodi **degni di nota / che meritano di essere ricordati**

Nota a margine: in gergo informatico, "storicizzare" significa "archiviare"